# Playing mp3 Websocket data with javascript in client browser

Tags: javascript, java, websocket, audio-streaming

I have a webSockets/NanoHTTP server application written in Java. The Java application records live audio from a microphone converted on the fly to mp3 and is remotely started/stopped through websockets from any/multiple devices/browsers which works fine.

```
while(bRunThread) {
    int cnt = targetRecordLine.read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.length);
    if(cnt > 0) {
        if(bRecording) {
            int bytesToTransfer = Math.min(buffer.length, tempBuffer.length);
            int bytesWritten;
            int currentPcmPosition = 0;
            while(0 < (bytesWritten = encoder.encodeBuffer(tempBuffer, currentPcmPosition,
                    bytesToTransfer, buffer))) {
                currentPcmPosition += bytesToTransfer;
                bytesToTransfer = Math.min(buffer.length, tempBuffer.length
                        - currentPcmPosition);
                fos.write(buffer, 0, bytesWritten);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to send the mp3 data to the listening browser(s) with minimal delay. The client side Websockets is all done in javascript. This will be on a local lan only but I want to minimize bandwidth usage. I cannot use webRTC as there are older devices that don't support webRTC but do support WebSockets.

I'd appreciate some demo code if possible for decoding/playing the mp3 data chunks as they come through websockets.

NOTE: I don't have to send mp3 data if that makes it more difficult. I can get the data before compression.